# symfony2: loading entities from web services

Tags: php, rest, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to load entities from a REST web service in the same way as I would from a database using Doctrin ORM.

Creating REST web services in Symfony is really well documented but I canlt see anythign about consuming them.

I've written losts of apps in straight PHP that load data from REST services but I'm sure there must me a bundle in Symfony that will do it for me in the same way as Doctrin ORM allows me to map to and from databases.

Is there something I'm missing or do I need to write my own custom repsitories to load entities from web services?

Comment: This could be helpful: http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle

Comment: Did you find any solution? I would like to take the same approach, at the moment I have created classes that take the web services responses and hold all the data as i would normally do in an entity, but I would like to know if there is a way to user directly the entities with repositories, that would be cool.

Comment: @soipo yes I used repositories. Basically in Symfony when your pulling data from the data base use use a findByID() function or similar which is implemented by Doctrin. To implement the same from rest I wrote repository classes with the same function names then wrote the code to  query and pull the data from the REST service and return the requires populated class(s). It's a case of writing it all by hand but it's pretty easy and fits with the MVC model.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a PHP HTTP client framework like guzzle, take a look at :

https://github.com/misd-service-development/guzzle-bundle

Comment: Yes, I already do for loading content. That doesn't solve the Object mapping bit that you get with ORM. I was hopeing there would be a framework for Object mapping REST web services.